# inserting a random generated number into a URL

Tags: java

Say I have a random number generator that generates numbers within a certain range. Is it possible to actually to somehow inject my random generated number into the my URL object so that every time the URL function is called, a new URL site is generated? For example:

```
int searchnumber = NumberGenerate();
new URL("http://api.zappos.com/Search?term=**searchnumber**&key=");
```

As far as I understand, the URL will literally take searchnumber as-is. I need to somehow not do that.

Comment: could you not use a timestamp instead of a pseudo-random number?

Comment: You can use [URI Templates](https://github.com/fge/uri-template) for that

Comment: You may want to describe the problem you are trying to resolve (create a unique, a semi-unique, a ?? URL), and when/how you want to use the  url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous ways to insert a variable value into a string, you can either contatenate using the "+" operator:

```
int searchnumber = NumberGenerate();
new URL("http://api.zappos.com/Search?term=" + searchnumber + "&key=");
```

Or use String's own `format` method:

```
int searchnumber = NumberGenerate();
new URL(String.format("http://api.zappos.com/Search?term=%s&key=", searchnumber));
```

However, there's no way to change the URL object automatically every time it's called. You can extract the URL generation to a separate function and call it every time you want to create a unique, randomized URL:

```
URL getUrl() {
    int searchnumber = NumberGenerate();
    return new URL("http://api.zappos.com/Search?term=" + searchnumber + "&key=");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might create a class (say, MyRandomURL) and method that returns a URL, so you can generate a new one everytime you call it.